# If ring $R\neq \{0\}$ then subring $R_0 \neq \{0\}$ (proof verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, rngs

I want to check my proof:

**Given:** Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and $H$ an additive subgroup of $R$. We define $R_0=\{x\in R : \forall h \in H \text{ we have } xh \in H\} \subset R$.

**To prove:** $R\neq \{0\} \Longrightarrow R_0 \neq \{0\}$.

(I showed that $R_0$ is a subring of $R$ separately, but I don't see how this would be relevant to what is asked here.)

**My attempt:** I wanted to show that $R_0=\{0\} \Longrightarrow R=\{0\}$.

Starting with $R_0=\{0\}$, we have that the only element $x$ in $R$ such that $xh\in H$ for all $h\in H$ is $x=0$. This implies that $0=1$, since $1\in R$ and $1h=h\in H$ for all $h\in H$.

I don't think this is enough to conclude that $R=\{0\}$.

So let's take some $a\in R$ such that $a\neq 0$. Since $H$ is an additive subgroup of $R$, we have that $ah \in H$ for all $h\in H$, since $R$ is closed under the ring operations. So contradiction: now $R_0=\{0,a\}$. So there is no such $a\in R$. So $R=\{0\}$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Is $1$ in $R_0$?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes. Since I assumed that $R_0=\{0\}$ then I had to put $1=0$.

Comment: OK, let's take a step back. If $R \ne 0$, then $1 \ne 0$. If you can show that $1 \in R_0$ from the defition of $R_0$, then you should be done, no?

Comment: If $1=0$ in R, then for every $r\in R,$ one has $r=1\cdot r=0\cdot r=0,$ showing that $R=\{0\}.$ By the way, your last paragraph does not make sense, because by closed-ness of ring operation, you can only say that $ah\in R.$

Comment: @AymanHourieh Ah yes, thank you! So actually doing the proof in the way I tried was not useful.

Comment: @Pythagoras I see why the last paragraph does not make sense now. Thanks! But so the proof up until that point is correct, it is just a question of seeing that $1=0$ in $R$ finishes the proof.